# How to reference name and surname of a user in CommCare

Tags: commcare

I would like to know how to reference in a hidden value the first and last name of a mobile worker in CommCare.

I researched and I was able only to reference the username and location name, but can't find the exact one for first and last name.

Answer (score 5):

In order to do this you need to use something called [Custom User Data](https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Custom+User+Data). In the calculate condition of your hidden variable you can use an expression like this:

```
instance('commcaresession')/session/user/data/commcare_first_name
```

And for the last name you can use:

```
instance('commcaresession')/session/user/data/commcare_last_name
```

The documentation will show you other examples of how to access things like the user's phone number.